# 3D plot with orthogonal style with diagonal axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection, diagonal, matplotlib-3d

I would like to plot a plot in the style how we are used to plot them in school. Here is an example:

[image: This is the projection I want ("like in school")]

Summary:

- 3D Plot
- the y-z plane is parallel to the screen (horizontal y, vertical z)
- the x axis is diagonal

The Y-Z Axis is parallel to the screen (horizontal y, vertical z. Usually the X axis would now point toward the screen. But I would like to change that so that it is directed diagonally downwards (like one would draw it on a sheet of paper sometimes). Unfortunately, I am not aware of how this projection is named (oblique image), but I am pretty sure it is orthogonal and that I need some kind of additional projection.

I have tried it with a custom projection for the axis like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', proj_type='ortho')

# Some sample data
x, y, z = np.random.rand(3, 100)
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

# Apply the transformation
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), transform)

# Set labels and view
ax.view_init(elev=0, azim=0)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# Manual transformation matrix
c = np.cos(np.deg2rad(30))
s = np.sin(np.deg2rad(30))
transform = np.array([
[1,  0,  0, 0],
[0,  c, -s, 0],
[0,  s,  c, 0],
[0,  0,  0, 1]
])

# Apply the transformation
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), transform)

plt.show()
```

This is my result (not very impressive so far :)
[image]

How can I fix this to look like the cube?

Comment: Your approach of transforming the projection is right so are you looking for the correct orientation and methods to adjust the visual aspects of the plot?

Comment: For 2D plots, matplotlib comes with the option to set the aspect ratio. Maybe there is something for 3D-plots as well?

Comment: @JesseSealand, it already helped me that you confirm my approach. And yes, that means I am searching for the correct transformation matrix and view now, I appreciate any further help

Answer (score 1):

#### Example Output

[image: oblique cavalier projection]

#### Solution

The projection you are looking for is a modified version of the oblique cavalier projection. In a typical cavalier projection, the xy-plane is parallel to the screen and the z-axis is diagonal with the positive direction pointing out of the screen. The transform matrix for this projection can be found on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection) with more information in these [lecture notes](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/%7Ecs155/Lecture_08.pdf).

It sounds like you would like the x-axis to point diagonally into the screen with the yz-plane parallel to the screen. Your code achieves as long as you change the `transform` matrix. When `alpha` is the angle of the diagonal the proper transform matrix is:

[image: transform matrix]

The -1 in the top left flips the diagonal x-axis. Playing around with the negative signs on the `cos()` and `sin()` terms will show you how the graph can be manipulated.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', proj_type='ortho')

# Some sample data
x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
z = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

# display data
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.plot(x, y, z)

# set angle of the diagonal (63.4 = arctan(2))
alpha = 63.4 

# Set labels and view and lims
ax.view_init(elev=alpha, azim=(90-alpha))
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax.set_xlim(-0.5,1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5,1.5)
ax.set_zlim(-0.5,1.5)

# Manual transformation matrix
c = np.cos(np.deg2rad(alpha))
s = np.sin(np.deg2rad(alpha))
transform = np.array([
[-1, 0,  0, 0],
[0,  1,  0, 0],
[-c, s,  1, 0],
[0,  0,  0, 1]
])

# Apply the transformation
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), transform)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: as of at least matplotlib 3.5.3, this code snippet does not work (not oblique perspective)